# When does a ring homomorphism exist?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I have been studying the basics of ring theory and ring homomorphisms. I know that for 2 groups, there always exists a homomorphism between them, namely the trivial homomorphism.

> Does a corollary exist for rings?  i.e., given 2 rings, does there always exist a ring homomorphism between them? If not, what extra conditions are required for a ring homomorphism to exist? Thanks.

Comment: Whether the zero map is a ring homomorphism depends on the conventions, see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/165503/is-the-zero-map-between-two-arbitrary-rings-a-ring-homomorphism).

Comment: The zero ring screws things up. It's the only ring where 0  = 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, in general there need not be a ring homomorphism between two given rings, e.g., there is no (unital) ring homomorphism between $M_2(R)$ and $R$ for the integers, $R=\mathbb{Z}$, see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1334276/is-there-a-ring-homomorphism-m-2-mathbb-z-to-mathbb-z).

Answer (score 1):

There is no (unital) ring homomorphism between $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Z}$. One of the description of the case when such map exists is when the codomain ring has a subring which is isomorphic to a nontrivial quotient of the domain ring. See the First Isomorphism theorem.

Answer (score 1):

For $p\not = q$ prime, any map $\mathbb{Z}_p \to \mathbb{Z}_q$ must vanish.

Answer (score 1):

Quite a lot of nontrivial problems can be expressed in the form
"does a ring homomorphism exist between two given rings".
As an example, let $f(X,Y)$ be a nontrivial polynomial in two variables
with integer coefficients. Then $C=\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2:f(x,y)=0\}$ is a curve.
The question "does $C$ have any point with rational coordinates" is equivalent to "is the a ring homomorphism from
$\Bbb Q[X,Y]/\langle f(X,Y)\rangle$" to $\Bbb Q$.